# How to shorten nested if-expressions?

Tags: java

Is it possible to somehow shorten many if-expressions?
Example: imagine 3 numbers, and each will only count up if the former one reached count of 10.

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;

a++;
if (a == 10) {
    a = 0;
    b++;
    if (b == 10) {
        b = 0;
        c++;
    }
}

return toString(a+b+c); //I know this is not valid
```

Is it possible to somehow shorten these kind of expressions?

Comment: i didn't get you ?? what you want ??

Comment: Is that code inside some loop?

Comment: Can you explain what is the intended output?

Comment: Why not just...`return "1"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax-wise, no. Not in Java. Your only way to do that is to improve your algorithm. I am not sure exactly what your algorithm is trying to achieve, but by the looks of it, you could reduce nesting by proper usage of collections.